# jQuery.ScrollTo - how to make bg to scroll slower than the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new to coding ,  and to this site, i hope you'll help me!     so i'm making horizontal website, i want to add scrolling background, that scrolls with other elements clicked, but slower 
like for example http://hotdot.pro/en/  .    How do i do that, where do i put code lines?

or maybe i could use better plugin?

Thanks for any help!

!!i'm putting script code here just because website says that my post is not informative enough. sorry

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.panel').click(function () {

        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });

});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}

</script>
```

or

where?

Comment: I see that you've tagged this question for [tag:java]. Of course you do know that Java != JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Parallax Plugin is probably what you are looking for.

See demo here: http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Source code and documentation here: https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax

"or maybe i could use better plugin" - rule of thumb is: whenever it is possible to use already written code (and not to write your own), you should do so. Except the cases, when writing a code is an academic exercise.